# CORS Issue with AJAX and Azure Reverse Proxy

Tags: ajax, azure, proxy, cors

I am having issues with CORS.
I have AJAX calls from an SPA in domain A to a REST API in domain C ( mine also ) via domain B which I have set up as a reverse proxy and load balancer.
All three are deployed to Azure Web Apps.

Calls from A to C  work direct with no issues. 
But calls from A to C via B will not work.

CORS is allowed on B and C from A using the Portal.
CORS is allowed on C from B using the Portal.

The Web.config of the API server C has the following :

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
    Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 
    The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

So, my understanding is the API server has to allow the SPA make the request, which is what I thought the lines above do.So does anyone have any idea whats going on with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can control CORS at the App Service, and that setting may be overriding your web.config. In the App Service menu scroll down to the API section and there is a CORS menu.

Since you're specify some allowed headers and methods that section might not work for you, but if you add a record for *, then remove it, it should start using your web.config based CORS handling.